# x265 - Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 (Apple Silicon)

Tags: apple-silicon

any ideas for this?
I try to build SDRangel on my M1 Mac but at 77% I get this error ...

```
-- GIT_EXECUTABLE /opt/local/bin/git
-- GIT LIVE REPO VERSION RETRIEVED
-- X265 RELEASE VERSION 3.5+68-40e37bce9
-- Detected CXX compiler using -O3 optimization level
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /opt/build/sdrangel/build/external/x265/src/x265-build
[ 27%] Performing build step for 'x265'
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target common
[ 45%] Built target common
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target encoder
[ 65%] Built target encoder
[ 76%] Built target x265-static
[ 77%] Linking CXX shared library libx265.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "x265_entropyStateBits", referenced from:
      _x265_costCoeffNxN_neon in pixel-util.S.o
     (maybe you meant: _x265_entropyStateBits)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[5]: *** [libx265.206.dylib] Error 1
make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/x265-shared.dir/all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [external/x265/src/x265-stamp/x265-build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [external/CMakeFiles/x265.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am stuck. Don't know what to try to solve this issue.
I did not find anything anywhere ...

Answer (score 2):

Working on it for most of 2 days, I did find this site that presents a working method of building libx265 stuff on Apple Silicon and works for me on macOS 13.0.1.  https://www.osxexperts.net/  Problem is, it only builds the libraries for building it into ffmpeg, no executable binary.

When I tried to get the executable also, by removing `-DENABLE_CLI=OFF` from the last cmake command, the error comes back.  Put it back in, everything completes without error.

Here is the full process that works for me (no executable).  It builds a multilibrary that can encode 8, 10, or 12-bit video:

```
cd x265/source

#### 12 bit
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${TARGET} -DHIGH_BIT_DEPTH=ON -DMAIN12=ON -DENABLE_SHARED=NO -DEXPORT_C_API=NO -DENABLE_CLI=OFF .
make
mv libx265.a libx265_main12.a
make clean-generated
rm CMakeCache.txt

#### 10bit
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${TARGET} -DHIGH_BIT_DEPTH=ON -DMAIN10=ON -DENABLE_SHARED=NO -DEXPORT_C_API=NO -DENABLE_CLI=OFF .
make clean
make
mv libx265.a libx265_main10.a
make clean-generated && rm CMakeCache.txt

#### 8 bit and all together
# removed  -DENABLE_CLI=OFF from last one so we get the x265 binary
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${TARGET} -DEXTRA_LIB="x265_main10.a;x265_main12.a" -DEXTRA_LINK_FLAGS=-L. -DLINKED_10BIT=ON -DLINKED_12BIT=ON -DENABLE_SHARED=OFF -DENABLE_CLI=OFF .
make clean
make
mv libx265.a libx265_main.a

# this is Apple's libtool
libtool -static -o libx265.a libx265_main.a libx265_main10.a libx265_main12.a
make install
```

When I remove the last `-DENABLE_CLI=OFF`, here's the error:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable x265
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "x265_entropyStateBits", referenced from:
      _x265_costCoeffNxN_neon in libx265.a(pixel-util.S.o)
      _x265_10bit_costCoeffNxN_neon in libx265_main10.a(pixel-util.S.o)
      _x265_12bit_costCoeffNxN_neon in libx265_main12.a(pixel-util.S.o)
     (maybe you meant: _x265_entropyStateBits)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [x265] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cli.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
JimsMBPro:source jim$
```

EDIT: @Peter Betz, see the [issue report](https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265_git/issues/623/missing-underscore-for-asm-function-needed).  Until the developers correct this error, it will compile if you edit `x265/source/common/aarch64/pixel-util.S`, line 2410.  Add an underscore as follows.  Change:

```
movrel          x1, x265_entropyStateBits
```

to

```
movrel          x1, _x265_entropyStateBits
```